# How to get pg_ctl reload to work? Asks for postgres user's password, but does not accept it

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I've installed PostgreSQL 11 on a CentOS 7 VM using `yum` as per the Postgres instructions on the site. After installing, I did

```
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-setup initdb
systemctl enable postgresql-11
systemctl start postgresql-11
```

and then went and configured the `postgresql.conf` file.

Now I need to reload the database so those changes take effect.

I tried `sudo pg_ctl reload` using the `postgres` account, which then prompts me for `postgres`'s password. This account was created with the initializing, to my understanding, and doesn't have a password, but just pressing enter is not accepted.

I then tried changing the password by doing `su -u postgres psql postgres` from root and in the shell executing `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'myPasswordHere';` which did return `ALTER ROLE` as confirmation. Retrying the reload as above, the new password still is not being accepted.

I then tried doing `systemctl restart postgres-11` as root, but that seemed to have completely broken the database, not allowing me to do any process involving the database or even access the Postgres shell.

I had to delete the data directory and rerun the `initdb` command above to restart everything (and the `pg_ctl` commands still doesn't accept my password).

How do I correctly reload the database so my changes to `postgresql.conf` are implemented?

Comment: If `systemctl restart postgres-11` "broke" your installation, then you probably did some changes to `postgresql.conf` that are incorrect and now Postgres refuses to start. Did you try to revert those changes and then `restart` the service? My recommendation is to not edit `postgresql.conf` directly but add a `custom.conf` with all changes and then include that at the end of `postgresql.conf` - that way you always know _what_ you changed any you can easily revert by not including the custom config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused on many levels.

1. Database users are different from operating system users.
   If you change `postgres`'s password in the database, the operating system user still has no password.

   I cannot see how that breaks the database though. Maybe your `pg_hba.conf` file is misconfigured.
2. You run `pg_ctl reload` as operating system user `postgres`, not as `root`, because `postgres` owns the PostgreSQL processes, so there is no need for `sudo` and hence no need for an operating system password.

You should probably read the PostgreSQL documentation about [client authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html) and [user management](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/user-manag.html).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Using `sudo` before the `pg_ctl` command seems to be the problem. Also I needed to do `pg_ctl restart` instead of 'reload', which worked. It did output a line saying permission denied, cannot change to directory "my current directory" despite me clarifying the data directory with the `-D` flag, but the reload still worked.